# Restore shell script linux

Tags: linux, shell

Hey I have this question for Coursework and I was wondering if someone could give me some help, as its coursework I don't want someone to just write the code for me, But could give me a short example or even tell me what kind of things I should use and I can read them.

I have a delete script which stores the location of the file that is deleted via
    `readlink -f $1` >>/root/TAM/store

The files are stored in the directory /root/TAM/dustbin when deleted

and the question I am stuck on is

restore  - This script should move the file called   back to its original directory without requiring any further user input. 
If a file of that name already exists at the restore location, the script prompts the user to select an appropriate alternative action.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete a file, you don't really delete it, but move it to your `dustbin` directory, keeping the full path from the root (so if you remove `/home/foo/blabla`, you store it in `dustbin/home/foo/blabla`.

The restore command/script then should verify, before restoring the file in the `dustbin` if there is a file with the same name in the original path.